# Can we use Would have in past hapitual actions and states?

Tags: grammar

Can we use would have for past habit?

For example: "Romans **would have travelled** by ship."

What is the difference between:

> I **would have expected** he would come here.

and

> I **expected** he would come here.

Answer (score 1):

"Would have" suggests that, because something was a habit or a common routine for the subject, it can be assumed they did it on a specific occasion.

Example:

> John would have used his car to get to work.

This suggests that it was John's habit to use his car, so it can be *assumed* with a degree of certainty that he used it for this purpose, or on a specific occasion.

While "would have" does suggest a degree of certainty, it is not used for an absolute certainty - in such a case we would say someone "did" do it, eg:

> John used his car to get to work

"Would" (as opposed to "*would have*") refers with certainty to that general habit, rather than to a specific occasion, for example:

> John would drive to work every day.

This refers generally to John's driving to work routine, not one specific occasion.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more natural to say

"I expected *him to* come here" (meaning that you were actually waiting for him to come).

or "I would have expected *him to* come here" (meaning that you thought it more likely than not that he would come).